# jQuery - store all form input values in a hidden input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to create a interface with a conditional logic that will allow the webmaster to insert advertisments anywhere on the site.
But before coding it, I need some advices from you :)

The forms are handled trough jquery & ajax. When the "add another ad" button is pressed a new form is created with jQuery.
My question is how could I gather all the form input values into a single hidden input that would look like:

`<input name="ad[]" type="hidden" value="homepage,after_article,4,visitors" />`

I think this value would be easier for me to handle in PHP.

[image]

Comment: mm.. wouldnt you need the key of the field with the value? i mean, instead of `homepage,after_article,4,visitors` wouldnt be better `foo:homepage,bar:after_article,n:4,baz:visitors`?

Comment: yes, it would probably be a good idea to include the key too. How do I do that?

Comment: you might find [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following to gather all the values:

```
var values = $('#yourformId :input').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).toArray().join(',');
```

and then set the value of your hidden field:

```
$('#ad').val(values);
```

And you can [see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/x2zZL/4/).

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
var values = $('#yourformId').serialize();
$('#ad').val(values);
```

[jQuery's form.serialize function](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)